# store array in data contract

Tags: c#, arrays

i have a data contract defined as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class DemoSearchList : ReturnValuesBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SessionId { get; set; } 

    [DataMember]
    public string[] StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string[] EndDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
}
```

as u can observe StartDate and Enddate are array of strings.
i want to send array of responses to these.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DemoSearchList.StartDate[i] = Convert.ToString(DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
    DemoSearchList.EndDate[i] = Convert.ToString(DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
}
```

DS is a dataset.
but i get an error as index out of bound . can anyone please help and also tel me if anything extra needs to be declared and used to achieve this

Comment: You cannot declare arrays with infinite or dynamic length. Prefer List<T> or ArrayList<T> instead, which will be more handy to add or remove and you can still convert it into an array, if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your array is has not the correct size or is not yet initialized. You need to do this before your for-loop:

```
DemoSearchList.StartDate = new string[DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
DemoSearchList.EndDate = new string[DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
```

But I would prefer to make a list instead of an array (if you don't need the index of each value):

```
[DataContract]
public class DemoSearchList : ReturnValuesBase
{
    public DemoSearchList()
    {
        this.StartDate = new List<string>();
        this.EndDate = new List<string>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then your for-loop could look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DemoSearchList.StartDate.Add(Convert.ToString(DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]));
    DemoSearchList.EndDate.Add(Convert.ToString(DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For using `Array` their `length should be defined`

```
StartDate = new String[10]; //can use data row count here
EndDate = new String[10]; //can use data row count here
```

if you want to use `objects of dynamic length` then use `LIST`instead

or change them to

```
[DataMember]
public List<String> StartDate { get; set; }

[DataMember]
 public List<String> EndDate { get; set; }
```